# how to hover images inside row

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox, zooming

I have 8 images in two columns on my website. What I want to do is to hover over them to make them larger. I don't know if my code is set up well for this, but I followed the code for displaying images in a column and using flexbox. It all looks like this.

[image]

I have tried many ways to get it to work, but nothing seems happening. It does respond on CodePen. What am I doing wrong?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 5px;
}


/* Clearfix (clear floats) */

.row {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.ruby {
  width: 174.6px;
  height: 202.6px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.ruby:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="row" style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; justify-content: space-around;">
  <div class="column">
    <img class="ruby" alt="Ruby" border="1" src="https://i.ibb.co/ncFyLQT/Ruby.jpg" /></div>

  <div class="column">
    <img alt="328361112-1238553170417968-3182757267401450434-n" border="1" src="https://i.ibb.co/Cv4xyh0/328361112-1238553170417968-3182757267401450434-n.jpg" /></div>

  <div class="column">
    <img alt="327493405-1261767694691294-7136147396263612670-n" border="1" src="https://i.ibb.co/GdfmMXx/327493405-1261767694691294-7136147396263612670-n.jpg" /></div>

  <div class="column">
    <img alt="328772606-513751557560461-3682142068132433242-n" border="1" src="https://i.ibb.co/RBRfLx2/328772606-513751557560461-3682142068132433242-n.jpg" /></div>

  <div class="column">
    <img alt="327105147-858413948750925-2985109477582386900-n" border="1" src="https://i.ibb.co/jMGJ4sW/327105147-858413948750925-2985109477582386900-n.jpg" /></div>

  <div class="column">
    <img alt="pirates-cj-Sparrow" border="1" src="https://i.ibb.co/Xxm5jfx/pirates-cj-Sparrow.png" /></div>

  <div class="column">
    <img alt="323052437-1325959481532753-51548628044621406-n" border="1" src="https://i.ibb.co/ySX0kfm/323052437-1325959481532753-51548628044621406-n.jpg" /></div>

  <div class="column">
    <img alt="327095010-854150125665734-8784794391710227960-n" border="1" src="https://i.ibb.co/rb4JRYS/327095010-854150125665734-8784794391710227960-n.jpg" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Based on what you have written in the question it seems to be working fine.

Comment: Hi @Kameron. Yes it works on CodePen fine, but not on my website. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, or if there's any problem with the code.

Comment: We will need some more details then on how your website is structured, etc.

Comment: It's a 3 column website. Maybe on this particular page, I shouldn't use columns?

Comment: I'm really stumped, because the code is exactly the same I put in CodePen.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: It seems whatever I try, it will not respond at all. I use Tumblr for my blog and coding stuff for it. It's really bizzare that it does not do anything at all.

Comment: provide a link to where it's not working.

Comment: Hi Kameron. I'm so sorry for my frustration. It's just that I've been at this for days without any conclusion as to why this is happening. Here is the link to the page that has the hover issue. https://iwriteonwheels.tumblr.com/Clockology

Comment: Thank you Kameron. I hope my link helped?

Comment: It did, see my answer below. Update your CSS to that CSS and it should work with no problems.

Comment: I just replied in comment to your updated answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252164/discussion-between-kameron-and-ladan).

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have the `transform` set on `.ruby:hover` when and in your HTML you don't have the `<img>` class set to `.ruby`. You have it set to `.image` as you can see in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoBuI.png).

Set the `:hover` on `.image` or change the `<img>` class to `.ruby`.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 5px;
}


/* Clearfix (clear floats) */

.row {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.image {
  width: 174.6px;
  height: 202.6px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.image:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="row" style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; margin: 1rem 0; justify-content: space-between;">
  <div class="column"><img alt="Ruby" border="1" class="image" src="https://i.ibb.co/ncFyLQT/Ruby.jpg" style="padding: 0.5em;"></div>
  <div class="column"><img alt="328361112-1238553170417968-3182757267401450434-n" border="1" class="image" src="https://i.ibb.co/Cv4xyh0/328361112-1238553170417968-3182757267401450434-n.jpg" style="padding: 0.5em;"></div>
  <div class="column"><img alt="327493405-1261767694691294-7136147396263612670-n" border="1" class="image" src="https://i.ibb.co/GdfmMXx/327493405-1261767694691294-7136147396263612670-n.jpg" style="padding: 0.5em;"></div>
  <div class="column"><img alt="328772606-513751557560461-3682142068132433242-n" border="1" class="image" src="https://i.ibb.co/RBRfLx2/328772606-513751557560461-3682142068132433242-n.jpg" style="padding: 0.5em;"></div>
  <div class="column"><img alt="327105147-858413948750925-2985109477582386900-n" border="1" class="image" src="https://i.ibb.co/jMGJ4sW/327105147-858413948750925-2985109477582386900-n.jpg" style="padding: 0.5em;"></div>
  <div class="column"><img alt="pirates-cj-Sparrow" border="1" class="image" src="https://i.ibb.co/Xxm5jfx/pirates-cj-Sparrow.png" style="padding: 0.5em;"></div>
  <div class="column"><img alt="323052437-1325959481532753-51548628044621406-n" border="1" class="image" src="https://i.ibb.co/ySX0kfm/323052437-1325959481532753-51548628044621406-n.jpg" style="padding: 0.5em;"></div>
  <div class="column"><img alt="327095010-854150125665734-8784794391710227960-n" border="1" class="image" src="https://i.ibb.co/rb4JRYS/327095010-854150125665734-8784794391710227960-n.jpg" style="padding: 0.5em;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok I just tried this. It's still not doing anything....